# How to call basic auth rest service fronted by API Manager?

Tags: wso2

I currently have services protected via basic auth. If I front those services with API Manager, I need to pass in the OAuth bearer token *AND* the basic auth token. So the curl call looks something like:

```
curl -v -u myusername:mypassword -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Authorization: Bearer 7a473720764791e63fe50934f416912" http://servicehose:8280/context/param
```

However, I get an internal server 500 error. How to call basic auth rest service fronted by API Manager?

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to call a secured service from API Manager. When creating the API you can provide the URL of the secured backend service and then apply "Secured" option for Endpoint Security Scheme field. When selecting this, you'll have to provide the credentials to access the secured service. With this, you can invoke the API, by only providing the Bearer token. API Manager will create the Basic Header when accessing the back end service.